# Grafana continuously get updated mySQL data

Tags: grafana

I have a mysql table that has the latest data on the status of certain critical processes across a number of Windows servers. I want Grafana to display a panel that shows the data in tablular format.
I got the data to be displayed. The problem is the table is tatic and to get the latest data from the mysql DB I need to hit the 'refresh' button. 
How do I do this say automatically every 5 minutes or a user chosen time interval? 
I'm using Grafana 8.5.2 locally hosted
The mysql table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE System_Status (
StatusDate datetime,
DisplayName VarChar(40),
status VarChar(10)
);
This table is to monitor whether a process on a number of given servers is running or not
So the status field is “UP” or “Down”
This table is updated every 5 minutes.
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

There should be a dropdown in the top right of your dashboard which allows you (or the user) to select the auto-refresh rate:

[image: auto-refresh selector]

You can save a default value after selecting an auto-refresh rate by saving your dashboard.